# ASP DropDownList selectedIndex is incorrect in codebehind

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a simple DropDownList where I have 6 listItems hardcoded. Item 0 only as text and does not have a value. When listItems 1-3 are selected, I am able to get the correct value in code behind but when listItems 4 and 5 are selected the value obtained in code behind is for listItem 1. I saw some posts talking about how I should use "Not Page.IsPostBack" to bind my control only on page load. But I don't this is my case. I have tried to do a databind for the control in the "Not Page.IsPostBack" but I get the same result. I also added a OnDataBinding event to my control that fires an alert. The alert only shows when the page is loaded and not on form submission. Can someone please help me to get to correct values for the 4th and 5th items and help me to understand what is going on here?

Thank you much,
Billy

Comment: Please include the problem code in your question. Also the code where you fill the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I wanted to use the same value for 3 of my listItems (1, 4 and 5). When I select item 4 or 5, the code behind used the first listItem that had same value (listItem 1) instead of the actual selected item. Once I used unique values for the listItems in question, I got the functionality that I was looking for. Now I just have to do a little extra processing in code behind to set the value that I want.